# How to convert uint32x4_t to uint8x16_t in Neon?

Tags: arm, simd, neon

Then what I mean is that I want to split each 32-bit unsigned int into four 8-bit. The corresponding bit not change.

If the `uint32x4_t` is:

```
01000101001111100000001000010000 | 01000101001111100000001000010000 | 01000101001111100000001000010000 | 01000101001111100000001000010000
```

I want to get:

```
 01000101 | 00111110 | 00000010 | 00010000 | 01000101 | 00111110 | 00000010 | 00010000 | 01000101 | 00111110 | 00000010 | 00010000 | 01000101 | 00111110 | 00000010 | 00010000 |
```

How can I do this?

Comment: I can't tell what the transform is. All the 0's and '1s are blurring together. You should do a better job of describing it, even symbolically: `ABCD -> BCDA`. But it looks like your first step is to cast the `uint32x4_t` vector to a `uint8x16_t` vector. Do that with `vreinterpretq_u8_u32`. Now you have a vector arranged in 8x16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `vreinterpretq_u8_u32`.  The prototype is:

```
uint8x16_t vreinterpretq_u8_u32 (uint32x4_t a);
```

*Edit*: as @EOF pointed out in the comment below, you may need an endian swap (`vrev32q_u8`) too.  GCC and clang define `__BYTE_ORDER__` (to `__ORDER_LITTLE_ENDIAN__` for little-endian and `__ORDER_BIG_ENDIAN__` for big-endian), or if you need something a bit more portable see https://github.com/nemequ/portable-snippets/tree/master/endian

Comment: Hi, I have tried this but it seems that the answer is not correct.

Comment: @Y.Zhu: You apparently don't know about *endianness*. You'll need a `VREV32.8` (aka `vrev32q_u8()`).

Comment: I probably should have mentioned that in my answer…  @Y.Zhu, ARM is bi-endian, so you probably want to add some code to detect it instead of just assuming little-endian.